# Children element not crossing root element's height in email

Tags: html, css

I am designing a email for company. The HTML and CSS are working properly when opened in normal browser tab (Chrome). But when it is pasted into the Gmail compose, some design irregularities occur. One of these design irregularities is the container (a children element) not crossing the height of mainContent (parent element).

I've used HTML and CSS.

```css
.mainContent {
  background-color: #72b84c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: -10%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 1px grey;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Our clients have received up 26.58% ROI on their investments with our data driven research advice.</h3>
  <h3>YOU CAN BE THE NEXT WITH OUR SERVICES</h3>
  <button><a href="https://www.example.org">BUY NOW</a></button>
</div>
```

It should generate same results on Gmail compose as shown in normal browser tab.
[The result I want in mailbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDIm1.png)
[The result I'm getting in mail compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSflL.png)

Comment: Doesn't that `top:10%` make problem?

Comment: Maybe you could provide a picture or draft of what you expect and what you get.

Comment: @Johnny how I add a picture

Comment: @AliSheikhpour how can I make the element cross the parent elements boundary

Comment: The current way to make children out of parent is OK but the 10% of what amount? do you have control on the heigth of parent? Does it acts against the mailbox template? @anjumehta

Comment: @AliSheikhpour yes. The height of the parent is fixed at 1000px.

Comment: You can inspect the element in the mailbox and check why the rule is being ignored.  Perhaps there are some general rules overriding your css rule.

Comment: @anjumehta You click on edit and then you can add a picture in the editor. There is a img icon in the topbar

Comment: @Johnny I've added images